# What does "Location Smoothing" do?

Tags: ingress

In the "Device" menu under "OPS" there is a setting called "Location Smoothing". What does that setting exactly do? I'm told that it sends and receives more frequent location updates but I can't be sure about it because I couldn't find any official sources.

What's the cost of turning it on? Will it create more traffic and increase my bandwidth usage or will it just increase the GPS updates and drain my battery faster?

Comment: I'm guessing it's essentially a low pass filter over your location data to prevent the game from thinking you've moved, for instance, 10m in some direction despite actually standing still.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The Location Smoothing option, when turned on, lets you get a more accurate location positioning by [using data from wifi networks and cell towers around you](https://plus.google.com/+Ingress/posts/dLUbMRkQf2z). It shouldn't increase bandwidth usage, but I'm quite sure it drains your battery faster.